# ¿Cómo puedo especificar la página del campo para el mergeFieldInfo en una plantilla en Adobe Sign API v6?

Tags: javascript, api

Tengo una plantilla con text field read only y quiero agregar información usando el endpoint POST /agreements: https://secure.na1.adobesign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/agreements/createAgreement

El problema es que quiero usar la misma plantilla para llenar 2 documentos (en consecuencia, existen dos campos con el mismo nombre), pero cuando agrego la información no puedo especificar en qué página está el campo, por lo que el valor predeterminado es establecido en los dos campos. ¿Cómo puedo especificar en qué página está el campo y llenar cada uno con información diferente?

La petición que estoy usando es:

```
{
 "fileInfos": [
   {
     "libraryDocumentId": templateId
   },
   {
     "libraryDocumentId": templateId
   }
 ],
 "name": "test",
 "participantSetsInfo": [
   {
     "order": 1,
     "role": "SIGNER",
      "name":"SIGNER1",
     "memberInfos": [
       {
         "email": signerEmail
       }
     ]
   }
 ],
"mergeFieldInfo": [
   {
     "defaultValue": "04/12/2022",
     "fieldName": "date"
   }
 ],
 "signatureType": "ESIGN",
 "state": "IN_PROCESS"
}
```

Entonces, ¿puedo hacer algo como?:

```
    {
      "page":1
      "defaultValue": "04/12/2022",
      "fieldName": "date"
    },
    {
      "page":2
      "defaultValue": "06/03/2023",
      "fieldName": "date"
    }
  ]
```